# Jquery - getting nodes from html string

Tags: jquery, html, string, parsing

I have a html string

```
$myhtml = '<div class="hello"><img src="/img/my/pic"/><p>this is a description">';

// the above line is made up it is actually much more complex and pulled in via ajax but you get the idea. 


$parsedHtml = jQuery.parseHTML($myhtml).
```

How can I pull out the individual nodes and the attributes?   Specifically how do I get the src attribute of the image tag?

Comment: What are you looking for? You can use any jQuery method on the parsed object so i'm not sure what are you expecting here?!

Comment: specifically looking for the src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that following this pattern:

```
var html = $.parseHTML( str ),
var nodeNames = [];

// Gather the parsed HTML's node names
$.each( html, function( i, el ) {
  nodeNames[ i ] = "<li>" + el.nodeName + "</li>";
  //You do your own magic here when src is found
});
```